# How to obtain this solution using ProductLog in Mathematica, found by Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I was looking at this step from Wolfram alpha

[image]

In the above $W$ is [LambertW](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) function which Mathematica calls [ProductLog](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html)

[image]

When I try to obtain this solution in Mathematica 13.1, it can not solve it. Then how did Wolfram Alpha obtain this solution?

```
eq = Log[1 - y[x]] - Log[y[x]] + 1/y[x] == x + C[1]
Solve[eq, y[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Adding `Reals` did not help.

To see the solution above produced by Wolfram alpha, you can type this command inside Mathematica

```
WolframAlpha["solve y'=y^2*(y-1), y(0)=1"]
```

Then when the result comes back to the notebook, click on the `Show steps` button on the top right of the result, and now you will see the above solution/step in the middle of the steps shown.

Btw, Mathematica also solved this ODE and gives same answer as Wolfram alpha.

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2*(y[x] - 1), y[0] == 1}, y[x], x]
(*{{y[x] -> 1}}*)
```

Which is correct solution. So it must have done same step internally. But the question why does the `Solve` command not work in Mathematica? Is there a work around to solve this in Mathematica as shown in Wolfram Alpha steps?

I also tried `Reduce` and it also could not solve it.  Is Wolfram Alpha getting smarter than Wolfram Mathematica?

V 13.1 on windows

Comment: If I combine the `Log` by hand, `Solve[Log[(1-y)/y]+1/y==x+c,y]`, I get `ProductLog` in V12.3.

Comment: @user293787 you are right! But I would have expected Mathematica to do this then. It looks like Wolfram Alpha is getting smarter than Wolfram Mathematica these days. May be because it uses A.I.

Comment: Personally I think Mathematica is conservative when dealing with branch cut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eq = Log[1 - y[x]] - Log[y[x]] + 1/y[x] == x + C[1];

Off[Solve::ifun]

(sol = Solve[ApplySides[Exp, eq], y[x]][[1]]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think this is something that Mathematica should have done automatically? Should I report this?

Comment: @Nasser - The solution throws an inverse function warning. Presumably, it balked at this and left it to the user to decide whether to proceed. It didn't give an erroneous result so I wouldn't consider it worth reporting.